# How do I get the how many days until my next birthday?

Tags: javascript

I tried this but it fails

```
var diffDays1=(function(){ 
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var secondDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear()+1,4,5);
var firstDate = new Date();
 return Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
})();
```

Wolfram alpha says it's 330 days, diffDays1 shows it's 359. This is probably due to daylight savings or something. Is there a way to accurately calculate days since without doing it server side.

Comment: The function doesn't always return the number of days until your next birthday. It returns the number of days until your birthday next year which happens to be your next birthday sometimes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you're basing the month on April being 4, when April is 3 in Javascript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

```
var diffDays1=(function(){ 
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    var secondDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear()+1,3,5);
    var firstDate = new Date();
    return Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
})();
```

Comment: what does the 1 represent here?

Comment: This doesn't work if the birthday didn't happen this year yet. I'll add a working solution below.

Answer (score 5):

Why reinvent the wheel??
Use [datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs)

and after:

```
var startd = Date.parseExact(ind, "yyyy-MM-dd");
var endd = Date.parseExact(end, "yyyy-MM-dd");
var diff = new Date(endd - startd);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
```

That's all folks!

Answer (score 2):

The moment.js library (http://momentjs.com) handles this and a lot of other JavaScript date issues very easily and nicely. The diff function (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)  will do exactly what you want.

The fromNow function is also super nice if want to display the number of days from now you could do something like:

```
moment([2014, 4, 5]).fromNow();
```

would produce something like "330 days" if it's 330 days away.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cleaner solution using moment, which handles all cases correctly (including today, upcoming birthday this year or not until next year, time zone, leap year, etc.):

```
const birthdate = '2018-12-15';
const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const years = moment().diff(birthdate, 'years');
const adjustToday = birthdate.substring(5) === today.substring(5) ? 0 : 1;
const nextBirthday = moment(birthdate).add(years + adjustToday, 'years');
const daysUntilBirthday = nextBirthday.diff(today, 'days');
```

Simple, fast, accurate!

Here's the same code, explained:

```
// This is the birthdate we're checking, in ISO 8601 format
const birthdate = '2018-12-15';

// Get today's date in ISO 8601 format
const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

// Calculate current age of person in years (moment truncates by default)
const years = moment().diff(birthdate, 'years');

// Special case if birthday is today; we do NOT need an extra year added
const adjustToday = birthdate.substring(5) === today.substring(5) ? 0 : 1;

// Add age plus one year (unless birthday is today) to get next birthday
const nextBirthday = moment(birthdate).add(years + adjustToday, 'years');

// Final calculation in days
const daysUntilBirthday = nextBirthday.diff(today, 'days');
```

If the birthday is today, the result will be 0; if it is tomorrow, the result will be 1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The selected solution doesn't work if the birthday is this year, because it sums 1 to getFullYear.

This is my solution, it also prevents two edge cases: birthday today and 1 day remaining.

```
const birthdayDay = 19;
const birthdayMonth = 11; // december === 11
const myBirthdayThisYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 19).setHours(23, 59, 59);

export const daysUntilBirthday = () => {
  const addToYear = myBirthdayThisYear > Date.now() ? 0 : 1;
  const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  const secondDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() + addToYear, birthdayMonth, birthdayDay);
  const firstDate = new Date();
  const days = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
  const daysOrDay = days === 1 ? 'day' : 'days';
  return days !== 365 ? `${days} ${daysOrDay} until my birthday ` : ' TODAY IS MY BIRTHDAY ';
};
```